# PL2303 cable subtype identification

Tags: usb-device

There are several [PL2303 serial cable sub-types \ revisions](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?pcid=41&showlevel=0017-0037-0041): the PL2303-HXD is the [D-revision](https://techblog.willshouse.com/2015/01/07/how-to-tell-if-pl-2303hx-pl-2303-is-3-3v-or-5v/).     A black PL2303 cable is provided to me. I would like to use it with a Raspberry Pi, which is a 3.3.V device.  If my cable is 5V, then I am concerned it will damage my rPi.

[image]

lsusb returns:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

What command-line tests can be performed to identify the cable and if it is a 3.3V or 5.5V device?

Comment: plug it in and and check the voltage between the tx and the ground. it should be 3.3v for rp. this is quite off-topic here.

Comment: afaik all pl2303 chips do BOTH 5v and 3.3v, they can be switched via a pin, which in adapters like that from the picture is fixed and cannot be changed. it's not a matter of "subtype".

Comment: @pizdelect  Thanks for the responses.  I have updated and narrowed the question to reflect a request a test from the UNIX command line.

Comment: There's no command line to detect that, believe me. Some pl2303 adapters (the kind without a cable, covered in a shrink wrap tube) have a jumper that can switch between 3.3v and 5v. Their price range is $1-$2 ;-). But it's probably a good idea to connect  to your rp via ssh, instead of the serial port, which is disabled in rp b4.

Comment: @pizdelect Agreed: SSH through the network is preferable.   The problem is that sometimes a network connection is not always available for a 'headless' pi.  Creative suggestions \ alternatives are always appreciated

Comment: The answer to your question is simply NO. No command-line tests could be performed to detect that. But you don't need a 3rd party network connection to connect your rPi to a laptop or phone. There are 1000 ways you can connect them: You can configure either of them to act like a wifi access point. You can connect them via an ethernet cable. Or an USB cable (USB-C or microUSB, depending on the model) and configure the rpi via the gadgetfs to appear as either a network or serial interface. Or you can buy two cables like that from the picture and cross-connect them: GND-GND, TX-RX, RX-TX.

Comment: And bluetooth works too.